# AngularJS ($http GET): $scope.names is always an empty array but call to back-end is OK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, debugging

The call to the back-end (GET /app/getNames) returns json array properly.

The problem is that $scope.names in app.controller.js always remains an empty array.

**app.controller.js:**

```
myApp.controller('myAppController', ['$scope','$http','myAppService',
        function($scope, $http, myAppService) {

            $scope.names = [];
            myAppService.getNames(function(response) {
                $scope.names = response;
            });

        } 
]);
```

**app.service.js**

```
myApp.service('myAppService', ['$http', function($http) {

    this.getNames= function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/app/getNames',
         });
     }

}]);
```

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(response)`

Comment: In addition to Anurag's question, I need to make sure this link is correct `url: '/app/getNames',` assuming API and the front part are in same host?

Comment: With `console.log(response) I was getting nothing. Url was also correct. I managed to resolve this by changing method to `myAppService.getNames().then(function(response) {...` and I then I changed `$scope.names = response.data` to get only necessary stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getNames()`-function in your service returns a promise which you are ignoring. You are invoking the `getNames()`-function and pass another function as parameter to it which is wrong.

To get the result of the promise you have to change the code in your controller to this:

```js
$scope.names = [];
myAppService.getNames().then(function(response) {
    $scope.names = response;
});
```